# Compare 3 csv Files with Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I need to compare 3 csv files to compare against 3 columns (all three columns have the same name on all 3 csv files), to count 1)what is duplicated and 2) what is different (counts only are fine).

Ex. csv1 colB needs checked and compared to csv2 colB and csv3 colb for count totals duplicated(matched on csv2,3) and coutn totals (matched on csv2/3).

All 3 csv's have same column names and colB has ip addreses, colC has hash values, and colD has domain names.

I have tried this for a test at matching colB with failure:

```
print(df[~df.colB.isin(df1.colB)]) #prints out all columns from df
```

Tried to add:

```
print(df[~df.colB.isin(df1.colB).count()]) #get multiple traceback errors
```

Comment: Are the indexes in your dataframes the same? I mean as in are the indexes the usual 0,1,2,3 etc.

Comment: Yes. They are all the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `value_counts()` you will get the values of True and False.

```
df.colB.isin(df1.colB).value_counts()
```

I hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks Karthik. Are the "False" value counts the duplicated counts? Can this be done adding a third csv lookup? i.e df2 along with df1.

Answer (score 1):

Let's call the dataframes `df1`, `df2`, `df3`.

Each column in a dataframe is a series, so you can compare them to get a boolean series:

```
checkB12 = (df1.colB == df2.colB)
```

This would give a Pandas series object that has (`True, True, False,...`) or something like that.

Similarly,

```
checkB13 = (df1.colB == df3.colB)
```

Then,

```
duplicated = checkB12 or checkB13
```

This gives you a series of boolean values, with true when there is at least one match of `df1` with `df2` or `df3`. Doing `duplicated.sum()` will give you the total number of True values i.e. the total number of cases in `df1` which is duplicated at least once in `df2` and `df3`.

I don't really understand what you mean by "what is different" between the dataframes, so I can't be sure what code you need.